# Compile without saving file

Tags: texmaker

I've been using TexStudio, but I realized that there is a delay in making document compilations a little bit bigger - when compared to TexMaker.

However, in TexStudio it was possible to compile the file without necessarily saving it. When trying to do this in TexMaker I can't.

So, is there any way to compile in TexMaker without necessarily having to save the file?

Comment: Texstudio first creates a temporary file in order to compile it. It's only hiding one step

Comment: texstudio and texmaker are simply the editors you use to write the file, the file has to be saved before latex can be run to produce the pdf. The editor of course may save it automatically or to a name such as "unnamed" if you do not explicitly save it. Saving the file should be an insignificant time compared to running latex

Comment: Some editors edit really a copy of the original file stored in a temporal directory, so you can compile the changes without touch the original file, but the file that you are really editing is always saved before compiling. And the compilation is never done by the editor.  They ony launch external programs (pdflatex, for instance).  Therefore,  except if some editor had some design problem, in the same conditions (same machine, same file, same compiler)  working directly with the original file should  be even faster (in practice you should not notice anything).